# How to read part of binary file with numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm converting a matlab script to numpy, but have some problems with reading data from a binary file. Is there an equivelent to `fseek` when using `fromfile` to skip the beginning of the file? This is the type of extractions I need to do:

```
fid = fopen(fname);
fseek(fid, 8, 'bof');
second = fread(fid, 1, 'schar');
fseek(fid, 100, 'bof');
total_cycles = fread(fid, 1, 'uint32', 0, 'l');
start_cycle = fread(fid, 1, 'uint32', 0, 'l');
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use seek with a file object in the normal way, and then use this file object in `fromfile`.  Here's a full example:

```
import numpy as np
import os

data = np.arange(100, dtype=np.int)
data.tofile("temp")  # save the data

f = open("temp", "rb")  # reopen the file
f.seek(256, os.SEEK_SET)  # seek

x = np.fromfile(f, dtype=np.int)  # read the data into numpy
print x 
# [64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88
# 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99]
```

Comment: Dang, file object instead of filename! This is exactly what I'm looking for, this should be added to the documentation for fromfile... Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There probably is a better answer… But when I've been faced with this problem, I had a file that I already wanted to access different parts of separately, which gave me an easy solution to this problem.

For example, say `chunkyfoo.bin` is a file consisting of a 6-byte header, a 1024-byte `numpy` array, and another 1024-byte `numpy` array. You can't just open the file and seek 6 bytes (because the first thing `numpy.fromfile` does is `lseek` back to 0). But you can just `mmap` the file and use `fromstring` instead:

```
with open('chunkyfoo.bin', 'rb') as f:
    with closing(mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), length=0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)) as m:
        a1 = np.fromstring(m[6:1030])
        a2 = np.fromstring(m[1030:])
```

This sounds like exactly what you want to do. Except, of course, that in real life the offset and length to `a1` and `a2` probably depend on the header, rather than being fixed comments.

The header is just `m[:6]`, and you can parse that by explicitly pulling it apart, using the `struct` module, or whatever else you'd do once you `read` the data. But, if you'd prefer, you can explicitly `seek` and `read` from `f` before constructing `m`, or after, or even make the same calls on `m`, and it will work, without affecting `a1` and `a2`.

An alternative, which I've done for a different non-`numpy`-related project, is to create a wrapper file object, like this:

```
class SeekedFileWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, fileobj):
        self.fileobj = fileobj
        self.offset = fileobj.tell()
    def seek(self, offset, whence=0):
        if whence == 0:
            offset += self.offset
        return self.fileobj.seek(offset, whence)
    # ... delegate everything else unchanged
```

I did the "delegate everything else unchanged" by generating a `list` of attributes at construction time and using that in `__getattr__`, but you probably want something less hacky. `numpy` only relies on a handful of methods of the file-like object, and I think they're properly documented, so just explicitly delegate those. But I think the `mmap` solution makes more sense here, unless you're trying to mechanically port over a bunch of explicit `seek`-based code. (You'd think `mmap` would also give you the option of leaving it as a `numpy.memmap` instead of a `numpy.array`, which lets `numpy` have more control over/feedback from the paging, etc. But it's actually pretty tricky to get a `numpy.memmap` and an `mmap` to work together.)

Comment: Old thread, but fromfile reads from the file position in a file. A lot of this machinery is unneeded and will be slower than numpy.fromfile.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I do when I have to read arbitrary in an heterogeneous binary file.
Numpy allows to interpret a bit pattern in arbitray way by changing the [dtype](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html) of the array. 
The Matlab code in the question reads a `char` and two `uint`.

Read this [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1102.1523.pdf) (easy reading on user level, not for scientists) on what one can achieve with changing the dtype, stride, dimensionality of an array.

```
import numpy as np

data = np.arange(10, dtype=np.int)
data.tofile('f')

x = np.fromfile('f', dtype='u1')
print x.size
# 40

second = x[8]
print 'second', second
# second 2

total_cycles = x[8:12]
print 'total_cycles', total_cycles
total_cycles.dtype = np.dtype('u4')
print 'total_cycles', total_cycles
# total_cycles [2 0 0 0]       !endianness
# total_cycles [2]

start_cycle = x[12:16]
start_cycle.dtype = np.dtype('u4')
print 'start_cycle', start_cycle
# start_cycle [3]

x.dtype = np.dtype('u4')
print 'x', x
# x [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]

x[3] = 423 
print 'start_cycle', start_cycle
# start_cycle [423]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a quite new feature of [`numpy.fromfile()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html)

> **offset** **int**
>
> The offset (in bytes) from the file’s current position. Defaults to 0. Only permitted for binary files.
>
> New in version 1.17.0.

```py
import numpy as np
import os

data = np.arange(100, dtype=np.int32)
data.tofile("temp")  # save the data

x = np.fromfile("temp", dtype=np.int32, offset=256)  # use the offset
print (x)
# [64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88
# 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99]
```