# Want to check this script I wrote to read a Fortran binary file

Tags: python, file-io, fortran

I'm working on a project that requires me to read Fortran binary files. It is my understanding that Fortran automatically puts a 4-byte header and footer into each file. As such, I want to remove the first and last 4 bytes from the file before I read it. Would this do the trick?

```
a = open("foo",rb)
b = a.seek(4,0)

x = np.fromfile(b.seek(4,2),dtype='float64')
```

Comment: Fortran _doesn't_ put a header/footer in a file.  For "unformatted" files (most likely what you have) you will often see a head and footer for each of many records in the file.  If you have such a file with more than one record just trimming the first and last four bytes typically won't do you much good at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be easier to read the entire file and then chop 4 bytes off each end:

```
a = open("foo","rb")
data = a.read()
a.close()

x = np.fromstring(data[4:-4], dtype='float64')
```

For a similar question, see [How to read part of binary file with numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14245094/584846)

Comment: Is there any benefit other than being easier to understand?

I saw that question but was unsure if how I applied it worked, thanks for the help!

Comment: According to the other question, `np.fromfile()` would rewind the file first so your method wouldn't work.  Not sure of any other benefits to this method.

Comment: This will work if he has an unformatted file with a single record, but is useless in the general case of multiple records.