# Fastest way to read in and slice binary data files in Python

Tags: python, matlab, performance, python-2.7, numpy

I have a processing script that is designed to pull in binary data files of type "uint16" and do various processing in chunks of 6400 at a time. The code was originally written in Matlab, but because the analysis codes are written in Python we wanted to streamline the process by having everything done in Python. The problem is i've noticed that my Python code is sufficiently slower than Matlab's fread function.

Simply put the Matlab code is thus:

```
fid = fopen(filename); 
frame = reshape(fread(fid,80*80,'uint16'),80,80);
```

While my Python code is simply:

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as f: 
    frame = np.array(unpack("H"*6400, f.read(12800))).reshape(80, 80).astype('float64')
```

The file size varies heavily from 500 MB -> 400 GB so i believe finding a faster way of parsing the data in Python could pay dividends on the larger files. A 500 MB typically has ~50000 chunks and this number increases linearly with file size. The speed difference i am seeing is roughly:

```
Python = 4 x 10^-4 seconds / chunk

Matlab = 6.5 x 10^-5 seconds / chunk
```

The processing shows over time Matlab is ~5x faster than Python's method i've implemented. I have explored methods such as numpy.fromfile and numpy.memmap, but because these methods require opening the entire file into memory at some point, it limits the use case as my binary files are quite large. Is there some pythonic method for doing this that i am missing? I would have thought Python would be exceptionally fast at opening + reading binary files. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a chance you could use [dask](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/) with [h5py](http://www.h5py.org/). Last year I did some massive simulations with millions of particles using these two packages.

Comment: Also have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245094/how-to-read-part-of-binary-file-with-numpy)

Comment: @romeric I am not sure dask would work as i'm using ".bin" files and a conversion to something like h5py would be counterproductive for the usecase. The data file format is something i currently don't have control of unfortunately. The second post seems to just be using a f.seek command in combo with np.fromfile. the issue i see there is i could go to the right location, but it would read the rest of the file into the numpy array which would overload memory in my usecase.

Comment: Doesn't `fromfile` have a count or size parameter?

Comment: It might help if you could separate out the times for `read`, `unpack` and `array` steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a chunk to a file:

```
In [117]: dat = np.random.randint(0,1028,80*80).astype(np.uint16)
In [118]: dat.tofile('test.dat')
In [119]: dat
Out[119]: array([266, 776, 458, ..., 519,  38, 840], dtype=uint16)
```

Import it your way:

```
In [120]: import struct
In [121]: with open('test.dat','rb') as f:
     ...:     frame = np.array(struct.unpack("H"*6400,f.read(12800)))
     ...:     
In [122]: frame
Out[122]: array([266, 776, 458, ..., 519,  38, 840])
```

Import with `fromfile`

```
In [124]: np.fromfile('test.dat',count=6400,dtype=np.uint16)
Out[124]: array([266, 776, 458, ..., 519,  38, 840], dtype=uint16)
```

Compare times:

```
In [125]: %%timeit
     ...:  with open('test.dat','rb') as f:
     ...:      ...:     frame = np.array(struct.unpack("H"*6400,f.read(12800)))
     ...: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 898 µs per loop

In [126]: timeit np.fromfile('test.dat',count=6400,dtype=np.uint16)
The slowest run took 5.41 times longe....
10000 loops, best of 3: 36.6 µs per loop
```

`fromfile` is much faster.

Time for the `struct.unpack`, without `np.array` is 266 µs; for just the `f.read`, 23.  So it's the `unpack` plus the more general and robust `np.array` that take so much longer.  File read, itself, is not a problem.  (`np.array` can handle many kinds of input, lists of lists, lists of objects, etc, so has to spend more time parsing and evaluating the inputs.)

A slightly faster variant on `fromfile` is your read plus `frombuffer`:

```
In [133]: with open('test.dat','rb') as f:
     ...:      frame3 = np.frombuffer(f.read(12800),dtype=np.uint16)
```

Comment: i was not able to get the combo of f.seek + np.fromfile to work, but the alternative you provided worked! Using the np.frombuffer (which i had never heard of before) i was able to get python down to 24 us / chunk which is about ~2 times faster than the matlab equivalent. Cheers.