# Why do we need numpy.fromfile if we already have numpy.load?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

### numpy.fromfile

According to [SciPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html) documentation

> Construct an array from data in a text or binary file. [...] Data
>   written using the `tofile` method can be read using this function.

So I just follow the instruction and create a file by using `tofile`

```
import numpy as np
A = np.random.rand(1000)
A.tofile('binary_file') # saving a dummy binary_file

x1 = np.fromfile('binary_file') # loading the dummy file

print(np.array_equal(A, x1)) # checking if the arrays are the same
>>> True
```

### numpy.load

At the same time, we also have `np.save` and `np.load`, which do exactly the save job as `tofile` and `fromfile`

```
np.save('file.npy',A)
x2 = np.load('file.npy')
print(np.array_equal(A, x1))
>>> True
```

### `fromfile` == `np.load`?

The two loading methods yield to same result as demonstrated below

```
print(np.array_equal(x1, x2))
>>> True
```

Then why do need both functions? Anything that can be done on `np.load` but not `fromfile`? Or vice versa?

Comment: You don't **need** to use the `tofile/fromfile` combination. The linked docs  says the `save/load` pair is better.

Comment: That's why I am asking this question. If `np.load` is better, and there's nothing can be achieved on on `fromfile` but not `np.load`, then why not remove it? Having `tofile/fromfile` will just cause some confusions here

Comment: `python/numpy` does not routinely remove functions just because there's a better alternative.  If there is a good case for removing something, there's a rather lengthy deprecation process to avoid breaking existing code. In a case like this, a note in the documentation should be enough to avoid confusion.

Comment: There's little reason to use the `tofile/fromfile` sequence instead of `save/load`.  But sometimes you get a binary file produced by some other source, and want to load it.   It doesn't have the header that `np.load` expects.  `fromfile` is a good choice, provided you know the correct `dtype`.  Here's an earlier SO example:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44169233/fastest-way-to-read-in-and-slice-binary-data-files-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fromfile` is the low-level function that is numpy calls within `load`:

- [`np.load` (aka `np.lib.npio.load`)](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/b4105bf03f16e0bd38c6a74ba32de5b0a69ed190/numpy/lib/npyio.py#L291-L466) calls `format.read_array` on line 452. Looking at the source for load, you can see it tries to guess what the right way to load a bunch of different binary file types is.
- [`np.lib.format.read_array`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/b4105bf03f16e0bd38c6a74ba32de5b0a69ed190/numpy/lib/format.py#L678-L770) calls `fromfile` on line 738. This loads from [the `npy` file format](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.format.html), which is a small header plus the raw binary data
- `fromfile` is a python wrapper around [`PyArray_FromFile`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/b4105bf03f16e0bd38c6a74ba32de5b0a69ed190/numpy/core/src/multiarray/ctors.c#L3731-L3802), which is a weird function that either loads raw binary data (the useful version), or loads text data in yet another different way.

Comment: Warren's answer is good, but your answer is even better. Since you show that `np,fromfile` is used in `np,load`, that's why we still keep `fromfile`.

Answer (score 4):

### fromfile == np.load?

No.  `numpy.load` reads files in the [NPY format](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lib.format.html). This is a specific format containing metadata that defines the shape and data type of the numpy array.

`numpy.fromfile` reads the raw bytes from the file. No metadata is stored in the file.  Your example with `A` happened to work because the default data type assumed by `fromfile` is `float64`.  Here's an example where it does not work:

```
In [25]: A = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40])                                                                                                              

In [26]: A.tofile('binary_file')                                                                                                                     

In [27]: B = np.fromfile('binary_file')                                                                                                              

In [28]: B                                                                                                                                           
Out[28]: array([4.9e-323, 9.9e-323, 1.5e-322, 2.0e-322])
```

Comment: It seems that `np.load` is better than `fromfile`. Is there's any situation that only `fromfile` works? Because I am wondering why this functionality is still here if we have a better option.

Comment: The Notes section of the [numpy.tofile](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tofile.html) docstring comments on its usefulness, and the Notes of [numpy.fromfile](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html) warn about using `fromfile` and `tofile` for long-term storage.